# Max Int Value for OCaml

Tags: int, ocaml, primitive

I just came off an interview where I needed to use this value for the algorithm I came up with. After the interview I was curious if there was actually a way to get the max Int value.

I am aware of Int32.max_int and Int64.max_int.

However when I set Int32.max_int's value to an int it exceeded the max value an Int have have.

```
# Int32.max_int;;
- : int32 = 2147483647l
# let a: int = 21474836471;;
Characters 13-24:
  let a: int = 21474836471;;
               ^^^^^^^^^^^
Error: Integer literal exceeds the range of representable integers of type int
```

Comment: Realized there was an l at the end of the Int32.max_int. Feels bad man.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$ ocaml
        OCaml version 4.01.0

# max_int;;
- : int = 4611686018427387903
# let a : int = max_int;;
val a : int = 4611686018427387903
```

**Update**

For what it's worth, if you're on a 32-bit system, Int32.max_int still doesn't fit into an int, even if you correct the mistake of thinking that the L (l) at the end is a 1:

```
# Int32.max_int;;
- : int32 = 2147483647l
# let i : int = 21474836471 (* Mistake *);;
Characters 14-25:
  let i : int = 21474836471 (* Mistake *);;
                ^^^^^^^^^^^
Error: Integer literal exceeds the range of representable integers of type int
# let i : int = 2147483647 (* No mistake *);;
Characters 14-24:
  let i : int = 2147483647 (* No mistake *);;
                ^^^^^^^^^^
Error: Integer literal exceeds the range of representable integers of type int
#
```

So I'd say the L wasn't the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Be aware that OCaml uses the high order bit of an integer for it's own purposes.

So an int is always one bit less than the machine native int. Modules Int32 and Int64 are for applications which need the corresponding full integer length, esp. interfaces to C libraries and functions.

Toplevel test:

```
# max_int;;        (* on 64 bit system *)
- : int = 4611686018427387903
# Int64.max_int;;  (* the lower case l is uppercase on my system *)
- : int64 = 9223372036854775807L
# let n = 9223372036854775807L;; (* correct type inference *)
val n : int64 = 9223372036854775807L
```

Hope this helps understanding it.

Comment: (OCaml uses the low-order bit, not the high-order bit.)

Comment: @JeffreyScofield thinking about it, it might be better not to mess with the sign bit.

Comment: The OCaml implementation is impressive in its economy of choices. Using the low bit works really well for distinguishing immediate values, because pointers virtually never point to an odd address. And arithmetic is pretty easy; e.g., for addition it's just one extra instruction to clear the low bit of one of the operands.